# Ошибка в MySQL запросе

Tags: mysql

```
DELETE FROM `users` `u`
LEFT JOIN `sessions` `ss`
ON `ss`.`id`=`u`.`id`
WHERE `id`=33
```

Где здесь ошибка?

А такой вариант работает:

```
DELETE users
FROM users
LEFT JOIN sessions
ON sessions.id = users.id
WHERE users.id=33
```

Но мне нужно, чтобы было похоже на мой первый пример.

p.s. Так работает:

```
DELETE `users` FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `sessions` ON `sessions`.`id` = `users`.`id` 
WHERE `users`.`id`=33
```

А вот так уже не работает:

```
DELETE `users` FROM `users` 
LEFT JOIN `sessions` `ss` ON `sessions`.`id` = `users`.`id` 
WHERE `users`.`id`=33
```

Comment: А какое сообщение об ошибке выдает `MySQL`?

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: В шапке добавил рабочий вариант, но его нужно сделать похоже на тот что с кавычками, почему то не получается

Comment: А чем вам не нравится второй вариант?

Comment: У меня используется конструктор запросов, нужно именно в том формате в кот сейчас не работает

Comment: можете дать скрыть создания таблиц? что бы можно было проверить ваши таблицы?

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev все эти запросы я выполняю на прямую сейчас, без конструктора, просто хочу составить рабочий

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev еще правки сделал, не могу понять все равно в чем причина

Comment: получается у вас алиас не срабатывает. сделайте в место `ss` только `s`

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev ничего не дало это, алиас убираеш и только тогда все работает

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему, так работает:

```
DELETE `u`.* 
FROM `users` `u` 
INNER JOIN `sessions` `ss` 
ON `u`.`id` = `ss`.`id` 
WHERE `u`.`id`=33;
```

Comment: Зачем же вы сниппет из него сделали?

Comment: @NickVolynkin это очень плохо? или хорошо? я непойму! В чем разница между просто строкой и строкой с такой обратной кавычкой ` ?

Comment: Для SQL-запроса хорошо так, как я сейчас оформил. А snippet'ы применяются для javascript и, кажется, html. Суть их в том, что они могут выполняться прямо на странице. Поскольку базы данных здесь нет, то и выполнять SQL-запрос нет ни смысла, ни возможности.

Comment: подробнее о форматировании вы можете прочитать здесь: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0):

Здесь не определено чья `id` указано.
При команде DELETE должна быть одна таблицаю

попробуйте так

```
   DELETE `u`
   FROM `users` `u`
   LEFT JOIN `sessions` `ss`
   ON `ss`.`id`=`u`.`id`
   WHERE `u`.`id`=33
```

Comment: Ваши варианты не работают

Comment: @sanu0074, и что же выдает `MySQL` в ответ на попытку выполнить запросы? :)

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: В шапке добавил рабочий вариант, но его нужно сделать похоже на тот что с кавычками, почему то не получается

Comment: попробуйте по поправке. Там результат должен быть одна таблица. А при `left join` получается расширенная таблица

Comment: так вот, я закавычил поправку сделал сокращения u и ss, и толку ноль, та же ошибка

Comment: а если использовать вложенный запрос? как в моей поправке ?

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev так получаю: #1093 - You can't specify target table 'users' for update in FROM clause. И добавил u вверх где users, получаю ошибку #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: при удалении не работает выборка вы правы. проверил только что. а вы пробовали так DELETE users FROM users u LEFT JOIN sessions ss ON ss.id=u.id WHERE u.id=33

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev так получил: #1109 - Unknown table 'users' in MULTI DELETE

Comment: попробуйте как в поправке. после делаете указываете не название таблицы а алиас таблицы